# Modal image not appearing correctly

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/6dhm0s8v/3/

The image does not fit inside the modal, no matter what size I make it. I've tried these for modal image

```
width: 500px;
max-width: 500px;
```

Neither of these work and the image goes right outside of the modal.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no `width-max` in CSS, it’s `max-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `img.modalImg` in your CSS instead of just `.modalImage` **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c6yhoxhx/)**

Also you might need to reset your `left`, `top` and `transform`.